# Field doesnt have a default value while importing excel laravel

Tags: laravel, import-from-excel

i want to import excel file to my database from the web. I have no idea what make it doesnt get the value from the excel, because i already try dd it and it shows the collection from the excel like what i want to do with it.
but its show error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'kode_matkul' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `kelas` () values ())

route :

```
Route::post('/admin/import_kelas_excel', 'DashboardController@importKelasExcel');
```

controller:

```
  public function importKelasExcel(Request $request) 
    {
        Excel::import(new KelasImport, $request->file('file'));
        return redirect('admin/list_kelas')->with('status', 'Excel Berhasil Diimport !');
    }
```

KelasImport :

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Kelas;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;


class KelasImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Kelas::updateOrCreate([
                'id' => $row['nomor'],
            ], [
                'id' => $row['nomor'],
                'kode_matkul' => $row['kode'],
                'nama_matkul' => $row['matakuliah'],
                'grup' => $row['grup'],
                'sifat' => $row['sifat'],
                'sks' => $row['sks'],
                'jumlah_mhs' => $row['jumlah_mahasiswa'],
                'tahun_ajaran' => $row['tahun_ajaran'],
                'semester' => $row['semester'],
                'jumlah_dosen' => $row['jumlah_dosen'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

model :

```
protected $table="kelas";
protected $fillable = ["kode_matkul, nama_matkul, grup, sifat, sks, jumlah_mhs, prodi, tahun_ajaran, semester"];
public $timestamps = false;
```

excel :
[image: data]

Comment: Can you share your Model and Migrartion as well?

Comment: @HassaanAli sure, i already update it my model

Comment: One of your excel rows which should have `kode_matkul` in it is empty

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand i already dd it and i check it 1 by 1 and the data is all filled